# PHP Variables for $_SESSION Variables

Tags: php, session

After I call `session_start()` is there anyway to assign shorter names to session variables and have those shorter names persist from page to page? For instance, if a user successfully logs in:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['email']  = $row->email;
$_SESSION['firstname']  = $row->firstname;
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$first = $_SESSION['firstname'];
```

Will `$email` and `$first` persist from page to page?

Comment: Session variables will persist, local variables won't. You can create new session variables with shorter names (transfer them the data) and destroy the originals with UNSET. $email and $first are not session variables, so they won't persist.

Comment: So you are saying that I can shorten `$_SESSION['firstname']` to `$_SESSION['first']` but not to `$first`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Not sure why it is a comment and not an answer. Can you move it to an actual answer so I can check it as the answer?

Comment: I believe you can't, but you could use something with a shorter name (like `$v = $_SESSION;` and `$v['var'] = value;` and then, at the end of your script, `$_SESSION = $v;`.

Comment: Another idea... `$variables_to_save = array('firstname', 'email'); $firstname = "something"; $email = "test@something.com";` and in the end of your script: `foreach ($variables_to_save AS $varname) $_SESSION[$varname] = ${$varname};`

Comment: Now it's an answer. ^_º

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use local variables, use session variables, example:

```
$_SESSION["shorty"] = $_SESSION["extremely_long_variable_name"];
unset($_SESSION["extremely_long_variable_name"] );
```

Destroy the original variable so it won't consume any memory. Local variable won't persist from epage to page.

Answer (score 0):

Those variables `$first` and `$email` won't persist.

I think the best option would be to add a piece of code at the end of the script that saves all relevant information into the session, or write your own class that wraps $_SESSION.

If you don't want to explicitly call it, for instance because your page has early exits, you can register a function that is called at the end of your script. This function can grab everything you need to persist and store it in $_SESSION.

Use [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to register such a function.